# Marklogic - How to assign dynamic variable in Xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have  tried below mentioned XQuery .

```
declare variable $path  as xs:string :="D:\Mongo\";

    let $uri :="/MJ/1932/Vol1/Part1/387.xml"
    let $x := fn:normalize-space(fn:replace($uri,"/"," "))
    for $i in fn:tokenize($x, " ")
    let $j := fn:concat($path,$i)
    return($j)
```

**Actual output**

```
    D:\Mongo\MJ
    D:\Mongo\1932
    D:\Mongo\Vol1
    D:\Mongo\Part1
    D:\Mongo\387.xml
```

**Expected output**

```
D:\Mongo\MJ
D:\Mongo\MJ\1932
D:\Mongo\MJ\1932\Vol1
D:\Mongo\MJ\1932\Vol1\Part1
D:\Mongo\MJ\1932\Vol1\Part1\387.xml
```

Please Suggest me , how to  change the dynamically variable value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XQuery is a functional programming language, which implies variables are immutable. You cannot simply increment or append to a defined variable. Typically, a recursive function is used instead to construct the result.

This examples (there are more concise ones, I wanted to keep the individual parts split apart and simple to understand) recursively creates the path, appending another level each time executed. The `$path` prefix is appended separately to not mix up the different tasks.

```
declare variable $path  as xs:string :="D:\Mongo\";
declare variable $uri as xs:string := "/MJ/1932/Vol1/Part1/387.xml";

declare function local:add-path($parts as xs:string*) as xs:string* {
  let $head := $parts[1]
  let $tail := $parts[position() > 1]
  return
    if ($head)
    then (
      $head,
      for $path in local:add-path($tail)
      return string-join(($head, $path), "\")
    )
    else ()

};

for $uri in local:add-path(fn:tokenize(fn:normalize-space(fn:replace($uri,"/"," ")), " "))
return concat($path, $uri)
```

In this specific case, an alternative would be to loop over a position counter and join the parts up to this position:

```
declare variable $path  as xs:string :="D:\Mongo\";
declare variable $uri as xs:string := "/MJ/1932/Vol1/Part1/387.xml";

let $parts := fn:tokenize(fn:normalize-space(fn:replace($uri,"/"," ")), " ")
for $i in (1 to count($parts))
return concat($path, string-join($parts[position() <= $i], '\'))
```