# XQuery: if condition inside a double for

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm trying to update a $numMatches variable inside an if statement, inside a double for, to keep track of the matches played by the teams in an XML document. The code raises an error.

The pseudo logic is:

"For each team in teams, for each match played, if the team's id is equal to the local or visitor player, add 1 to the number of matches played by that team".

The XQuery I tried is:

```
<resumen>    
{ for $teams in ligue/teams/team

    let $numMatches := 0

    for $matches in ligue/match_results/match

        if ($teams/team_id = $matches/local) or ($teams/team_id = 
        $matches/visitor) then

        $numMatches := $numMatches + 1

    return <teamAndMatches>{$teams/name/data()}-{$numMatches}</teamAndMatches>   
}
</resumen>
```

There is an error there, as XBase says it expects a return. Where is the error? I'm new to this language. Thanks!

Comment: Right at the requirements stage, try to express the requirement as a function (a relationship between the input and the output) rather than as an algorithm (a series of steps to be carried out). That will translate much more easily and naturally into XQuery. Viz: "For each team in teams, for each match played, show the number of matches played by that team where the team's id is equal to the local or visitor player" (though I don't know what it means for an id to be equal to a player).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `count` function so doing

```
<resumen>    
{ for $teams in ligue/teams/team

    return <teamAndMatches>{$teams/name/data()}-{count(ligue/match_results/match[local = $teams/team_id or visitor = $teams/team_id])}</teamAndMatches>   
}
</resumen>
```

should suffice.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> XQuery (XML Query) is a query and functional programming language that queries and transforms collections of structured and unstructured data, usually in the form of XML, text and with vendor-specific extensions for other data formats (JSON, binary, etc.).

quoted from the [WikiPedia XQuery article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery).

> XQuery is a functional programming language, which implies variables are immutable.

quoted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36267975/1305969).

So you cannot update your variable like this

```
$numMatches := $numMatches + 1
```

because the variable is immutable.
You were thinking from an imperative paradigm which doesn't apply here.

If you want to solve this riddle, try thinking from a *functional paradigm* and reprogram this function recursively (which probably means passing the counters as parameters to the recursive function).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have this information, that XQuery is a functional programming language. So far we haven't gotten to declaring functions in class, so I will stick to my current level solving-problems style.